# myql: sum up each day's sell total for each store

Tags: mysql

the table is:

```
mysql> DESC sell_data;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(64)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(128) | NO   |     |                     |                |
| sell_date  | datetime     | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| sell_price | double       | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| cost       | double       | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| store_id   | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

I attached the table struct as a picture, looks like the editor does support the format well.

There are 100 records in this table, and request to sum up each day's sell total in a given week for each store, which means for each given store id, need 7 subtotals, the result would be like:

```
store 1: 122  123  124  125  126  127  128
store 2: 131  122  133  134  135  136  137
```

....

this is very diffcult for me, request help, much apperaciated.
:)

I tried to group the data by "GROUP BY", like:

```
SELECT store_id
     , SUM(cost) AS all_cost
     , SUM(sell_price) AS all_price 
FROM sell_data 
WHERE sell_date BETWEEN '2017-10-12' AND '2017-10-15' 
GROUP BY store_id;
```

but it only gives the sum data for each store, not data for each day, totally stuck here.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you've tried, and where you're getting stuck. Right now, your question is asking others to write code for you.

Comment: Also: please learn about proper formatting. Two of us have already corrected your formatting, and you just undid our edits and replaced them with an image link pointing to what your table looks like. I rolled back this edit. It's straightforward to format code (there's even a code-formatting helper button in the editor). And nobody should have to click on a link to see your schema.

Comment: Looks to me your going to need some kind of pivot query.

Comment: You need to use [dayofweek()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function on your date and a case statement to get your 7 columns.

Comment: Do you want the sum of cost or sum of price, your example lists 8 columns whereas your SQL lists both cost & price.  Do you want both or just 1?

Comment: Incidentally, costs and prices are never double. It's why DECIMAL was invented - and the number in parentheses after the INT is meaningless. Omit it.

Comment: @Strawberry.  I need to get in the habit of reading the whole question and information provided and look at the whole not just the question. You do this and I commend you for it.  double for a price (oi-vey) and int with a #.

Comment: @xQbert Thanks for them nice words :-)

Comment: @Skyland06 Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me you going to need a pivot query. 
This is done by using GROUP BY in combination with SUM and CASE

```
SELECT
   SUM(
     CASE
      WHEN DAYNAME(sell_date) = 'Monday'
      THEN sell_price
      ELSE 0 
    END 
   ) 
    AS 
     Monday
 , SUM(
     CASE
      WHEN DAYNAME(sell_date) = 'Tuesday'
      THEN sell_price
      ELSE 0 
    END 
 ) 
  AS 
   Tuesday
 , SUM(
     CASE
      WHEN DAYNAME(sell_date) = 'Wednesday'
      THEN sell_price
      ELSE 0 
    END 
 ) 
  AS 
   Wednesday
 , SUM(
     CASE
      WHEN DAYNAME(sell_date) = 'Thursday'
      THEN sell_price
      ELSE 0 
    END 
 ) 
  AS 
   Thursday
 , SUM(
     CASE
      WHEN DAYNAME(sell_date) = 'Friday'
      THEN sell_price
      ELSE 0 
    END 
 ) 
  AS 
   Friday
 , SUM(
     CASE
      WHEN DAYNAME(sell_date) = 'Saturday'
      THEN sell_price
      ELSE 0 
    END 
 ) 
  AS 
   Saturday
 , SUM(
     CASE
      WHEN DAYNAME(sell_date) = 'Sunday'
      THEN sell_price
      ELSE 0 
    END 
 ) 
  AS 
   Sunday
FROM 
 [table]
WHERE
 WEEK(sell_date) = [week_number]
GROUP BY 
 store_id
ORDER BY 
 store_id ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying your query, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
 group by store_id, date(sell_date)
```

You probably want to add that to your select too

Answer (score -1):

Use sum(sell_price) with group by store_id

Comment: This doesn't account for individual days. (also, it's not a complete solution; best left as a comment, though the OP updated their question to show they're already using `sum()`).